# how to calculate two textbox values of a gridview items template text box values using Angular js

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs

i want to calculate two text box values and show the result in another text box within a `gridview`. The `gridview` control has 3 columns: `qty`, `unit price` and `total`. Total column should auto calculated using `AngularJS`. I'm unable to bind two text boxes.its coming `NaN` in total column.

```html
<div ng-app>
    <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gridviewCalc" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowEditing="gridviewCalc_RowEditing" AutoGenerateEditButton="true">
        <Columns>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="QTY" >
              <ItemTemplate>

                     <asp:TextBox runat="server"  Text='<%# Eval("qty")%>' ng-model="qty"/>
                  </ItemTemplate>

          </asp:TemplateField>

             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Unit Price">
              <ItemTemplate>

                  <asp:TextBox runat="server"  Text='<%# Eval("unitprice")%>' ng-model="unitprice"/>
                  </ItemTemplate>


          </asp:TemplateField>
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total">
              <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:TextBox runat="server"  Text='{{qty+unitprice}}'/>
                  </ItemTemplate>

          </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

</div>
```

Comment: I do not see any textboxes.

Comment: ok even label values are not getting

Comment: Try changing `Text='{{qty+unitprice}}'` to `ng-model=total` and in controller, `$scope.total = $scope.qty + $scope.unitprice;`

Answer (score 0):

instead of lable try this

```
<span>
 <%# String.Format("{0}",Convert.ToInt32(Eval("qty")) * Convert.ToInt32(Eval("unitprice"))) %>
</span>
```

for textbox try this to bind data.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server"  Text='<%# Bind("qty")%>'/>
```

BTW why you want to do calculation only in angular while you having asp rendering data for you.

Comment: angular js is not necessary , but i just want to calculate two columns values of text boxes and populate in total column in gridview itemtemplate

Comment: did you try my answer?

Comment: i tried with span its working . but i want in text box. while using with text box it giving error. showing value like this <%# String.Format("{0}",Convert.ToInt32(Eval("qty")) * Convert.ToInt32(Eval("unitprice"))) %>>

Comment: in textbox use `Bind` instead `Eval`.see the updated answer.

Comment: im not calculating database values. i just want to enter 2 values and calcilate and populate in text box. then i will insert into db. i used bind giving same answer

Comment: so now you want this calculated value in textbox? first you posted the question with label.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104709/discussion-between-krishna-mohan-and-pavan-teja).